# Qt5: Application crash on exit

Tags: c++, qt

I have a c++ program written in Qt5 5.14.1.
It also use `privoxy` source code inside.

```
System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6b8e17fa __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6b99ebc1 pthread_kill + 432
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff6b868ab6 __abort + 139
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff6b868a2b abort + 135
4   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010b807de9 qt_message_fatal(QtMsgType, QMessageLogContext const&, QString const&) + 9
5   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010b809534 QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const + 202
6   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010b81060d QThread::~QThread() + 189
7   com.yourcompany.xxxxxxxx        0x00000001099cc935 PrivoxyThread::~PrivoxyThread() + 21 (privoxythread.cpp:17)
8   com.yourcompany.xxxxxxxx        0x00000001099cc955 PrivoxyThread::~PrivoxyThread() + 21 (privoxythread.cpp:17)
9   com.yourcompany.xxxxxxxx        0x00000001099cc979 PrivoxyThread::~PrivoxyThread() + 25 (privoxythread.cpp:15)
10  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010ba0f394 QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren() + 228
11  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010ba0f128 QObject::~QObject() + 2088
12  com.yourcompany.xxxxxxxx        0x00000001099e4598 Connection::~Connection() + 88 (connection.cpp:38)
13  com.yourcompany.xxxxxxxx        0x00000001099e4695 Connection::~Connection() + 21 (connection.cpp:38)
14  com.yourcompany.xxxxxxxx        0x00000001099e4819 Connection::~Connection() + 25 (connection.cpp:36)
15  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010ba0f394 QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren() + 228
16  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010ba0f128 QObject::~QObject() + 2088
17  com.yourcompany.xxxxxxxx        0x0000000109b9bd75 ConnectionItem::~ConnectionItem() + 21 (connectionitem.h:26)
18  com.yourcompany.xxxxxxxx        0x0000000109b9a0c5 ConnectionItem::~ConnectionItem() + 21 (connectionitem.h:26)
19  com.yourcompany.xxxxxxxx        0x0000000109b9a0e9 ConnectionItem::~ConnectionItem() + 25 (connectionitem.h:26)
20  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010ba0f394 QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren() + 228
21  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010ba0f128 QObject::~QObject() + 2088
22  com.yourcompany.xxxxxxxx        0x00000001099efe1d ConnectionTableModel::~ConnectionTableModel() + 61 (connectiontablemodel.cpp:8)
23  com.yourcompany.xxxxxxxx        0x00000001099efe65 ConnectionTableModel::~ConnectionTableModel() + 21 (connectiontablemodel.cpp:8)
24  com.yourcompany.xxxxxxxx        0x00000001099efe89 ConnectionTableModel::~ConnectionTableModel() + 25 (connectiontablemodel.cpp:8)
25  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010ba0f394 QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren() + 228
26  org.qt-project.QtWidgets        0x000000010a9f7dae QWidget::~QWidget() + 1006
27  com.yourcompany.xxxxxxxx        0x0000000109a0c789 MainWindow::~MainWindow() + 409 (mainwindow.cpp:166)
28  com.yourcompany.xxxxxxxx        0x0000000109a0c825 MainWindow::~MainWindow() + 21 (mainwindow.cpp:166)
29  com.yourcompany.xxxxxxxx        0x00000001099fefcb main + 1339 (main.cpp:98)
30  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6b79a7fd start + 1
```

Each time I click quit, or `Command + Q`. It will quit and crash.
Is there a way to determine what cause the issue?
Apple Will pop a window when application crash, this is very annoying.

Comment: It seems like abort is being called as a result of something calling qfatal(). Are you able to see a message logged by qfatal (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qFatal) or can you attach a debugger to see where this has happened?

Comment: After I have attached debuger, the result is same above.

Comment: Looks like the `QThread` destructor is called while the thread is still running.  You need to establish where that's happening in your own code (`Connection` or `ConnectionItem` destructor?) and arrange for a more controlled termination of the `QThread`.

Comment: Might be a double deletion of a memory through the same pointer.

Comment: I think it's relevant to privoxy. After I disable privoxy main method, the error will never appear. However, I have to privoxy in my software

Comment: I disable the privoxy log system. And finally I got some errors. ``QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running``

Comment: You’ll need to tell the thread to shut down, and then call .wait() on it.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. However it gave me a segmentation fault 11. I changed ``privoxy = new PrivoxyThread(this);`` to ``privoxy = new PrivoxyThread();`` and no crash appear.